# Migrating cURL request to WGET request for logging into website not working

Tags: php, curl, wget

I have some code to login to a website via cURL:

```
    $url = "https://www.site.net/post/login.page"; 
    $cookie = "cookie.txt"; 

    $postdata = "screenName=$username&kclq=$password&submitEvent=1&TCNK=authenticationEntryComponent&enterClicked=true&ajaxSupported=yes"; 

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D167 Safari/9537.53"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.site.net/Index.page"); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I need to be able to change the user agent on the fly, and I can't really do that to my knowledge.  So I decided to migrate over to WGET:

```
shell_exec("wget -qO- --max-redirect=1 --save-cookies=\"cookie.txt\" --referer=\"https://www.site.net/Index.page\" --user-agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D167 Safari/9537.53\" --post-data=\"screenName=$username&kclq=$password&submitEvent=1&TCNK=authenticationEntryComponent&enterClicked=true&ajaxSupported=yes\" https://www.site.net/post/login.page");
```

However, this isn't even saving cookies to a file.  What am I doing wrong/what should I modify?

Comment: All you need to do is change the string for the user-agent option... why switch everything when you already have the code in place?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working.  Basically I'm using cURL to log in and then getting pages through WGET.  However, passing `--user-agent` does not seem to switch the user agent.

Comment: Don't use wget.  You have cURL... why would you use cURL and wget?

Comment: Oh yeah...why am I doing that?

Comment: @Someone, Hehe funny.

Comment: If someone wants to just answer this question I will accept their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can happen that your `wget` version doesn't support `--max-redirect=1` So remove that param from your command and try again. And it should work for you.

**Alternately**, the curl commandline:

```
curl -L -X POST --cookie-jar "cookie.txt" --referer "https://www.site.net/Index.page" --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D167 Safari/9537.53" --data "screenName=$username&kclq=$password&submitEvent=1&TCNK=authenticationEntryComponent&enterClicked=true&ajaxSupported=yes" http://localhost/post.php
```

**Another option**, change the agent from your php script in this way:

Add the following line at the top of your php script:

```
$agent = "Mozilla 6.0";
if(isset($_GET['agent'])){
    $agent = $_GET['agent'];
}
```

And change your curl code for this line `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` with the following one:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
```

Now browse your php script from browser like this way:

```
http://yourdomain/code.php?agent=Opera 9.0
```